# How to group similar rows?

Tags: python

Hey guys I have a question for grouping rows based on a name.

Below is my dataset:

```
Name      University            Subject              

John      Harvard               English, French
John      MIT                   Economics
Alan      BU                    Data Science
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
Name   Harvard   MIT   BU    English   French   Economics   Data Science
  
John      1       1     0       1         1        1            0
Alan      0       0     1       0         0        0            1
```

Please let me know how to do this in Python. I am quite new to this, I understand that we can use one hot encoding to create binary variables but I am not sure how to merge the rows based on the same name and separate the subjects.

1. How do you merge the rows based on the same name?
2. How do you create separate columns as for subjects separated by ","
3. How do you create binary variables for all of this after?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information? Do you have to use pure Python, or are you willing/able to use libraries? What have you tried thus far that has / hasn't worked, and what errors or specific issues have you run into? This will help people help you!

Comment: Thank you for the reply Adam.

Yes, unfortunately, I have to use Python since my entire project is based on this plus this is the only language I know apart from Excel. The dataset is too large for Excel.

I managed to separate the subjects and create dummy variables by using dt = dt['subject'].str.get_dummies(sep=','). Same method was used to create dummys for the universities. However, I am not sure how to merge the rows together.

Comment: Sorry to clarify I when I said "pure Python" I meant can you use other *Python* libraries, such as [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) and [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/). If so, your problem gets a lot easier, but sometimes (for a variety of reasons) people are restricted to just finding solutions in a base language.

Comment: Yes, I am open to using any libraries in python especially numpy and pandas.

Comment: Oh great! In that case, I'd suggest creating a `pandas` dataframe from the original data, and then you can just use [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) to encode the `University` and `Subject` columns

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean by this. I already have the dataframe. I believe it is a Pandas dataframe since I use pd.read_csv('f'ile name'') to read the file in the first place.

Comment: Could you please show me the code. Would really appreciate it :)

Comment: I'd be happy to try to help more, but could you edit your original question? If you include some information about the data (what format is it in?), some code that loads that format into Python (e.g. via [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)), and an attempt to call `get_dummies` then I can work with you from there

Answer (score 1):

For a beginner your question is quite involved. With `pandas` you can do the following.

**This step is not necessary when you load your data from a file.**
Setup the dataframe with text input.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

t =  '''
Name      University            Subject              

John      Harvard               English, French
John      MIT                   Economics
Alan      BU                    Data Science'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
df
```

Out:

```
   Name University          Subject
0  John    Harvard  English, French
1  John        MIT        Economics
2  Alan         BU     Data Science
```

In column `Subject` [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) multiple values in one row into a list

```
df['Subject'] = df.Subject.str.split(', ')
```

[`Explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the lists and [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to long data format. Remember the order of the columns

```
ser = df.explode('Subject').melt('Name').drop('variable', 1)
order = ser.value.unique()
```

Get binary variables with [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and [`groupby('Name')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
(pd.get_dummies(
    ser, columns=['value'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
    .groupby('Name', sort=False).max()
)[order]
```

Out:

```
      Harvard  MIT  BU  English  French  Economics  Data Science
Name                                                            
John        1    1   0        1       1          1             0
Alan        0    0   1        0       0          0             1
```

Comment: I am trying to understand this since I have not done anything like this before... thank you so much.

Will follow up if I have more questions.